# SIGSEGV when convertPoint:fromLayer: is called

Tags: ios, crash, segmentation-fault, hockeyapp

My app relatively often crashes with SIGSEGV. Unfortunately, I can not reproduce the crash and only see crash reports in Hockeyapp. I tried turning zombies on, too.

Looking at the crash report it seems that app crashes when processing touches (when user scrolling or something like this). No my app code mentioned in the stack trace.

The question is: how is it possible to have memory issue in this scenario? What would you recommend to reproduce and fix the issue?

```
Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0x71a86113
Crashed Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: convertPoint:fromLayer:

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x2106fae6 objc_msgSend_stret + 6
1   UIKit                                0x25e7a349 -[UIView(Geometry) convertPoint:fromView:] + 98
2   UIKit                                0x25e7e987 __38-[UIView(Geometry) hitTest:withEvent:]_block_invoke + 104
3   CoreFoundation                       0x217e8279 __53-[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 86
4   CoreFoundation                       0x217e81a7 -[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 248
5   UIKit                                0x25e7e447 -[UIView(Geometry) hitTest:withEvent:] + 492
6   UIKit                                0x26146f0d -[UIView(Geometry) _hitTest:withEvent:windowServerHitTestWindow:] + 62
7   UIKit                                0x25e7e9bd __38-[UIView(Geometry) hitTest:withEvent:]_block_invoke + 158
8   CoreFoundation                       0x217e8279 __53-[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 86
9   CoreFoundation                       0x217e81a7 -[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 248
10  UIKit                                0x25e7e447 -[UIView(Geometry) hitTest:withEvent:] + 492
11  UIKit                                0x26146f0d -[UIView(Geometry) _hitTest:withEvent:windowServerHitTestWindow:] + 62
12  UIKit                                0x26136491 __70+[UIWindow _hitTestToPoint:forEvent:windowServerHitTestWindow:screen:]_block_invoke + 186
13  UIKit                                0x25e4783f +[UIWindow _topVisibleWindowPassingTest:] + 156
14  UIKit                                0x26136399 +[UIWindow _hitTestToPoint:forEvent:windowServerHitTestWindow:screen:] + 142
15  UIKit                                0x26136629 -[UIWindow _targetWindowForPathIndex:atPoint:forEvent:windowServerHitTestWindow:onScreen:] + 158
16  UIKit                                0x260ffb61 _UIApplicationHandleDigitizerEvent + 10982
17  UIKit                                0x25e4123f _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 3836
18  CoreFoundation                       0x21889dff __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
19  CoreFoundation                       0x218899ed __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 450
20  CoreFoundation                       0x21887d5b __CFRunLoopRun + 792
21  CoreFoundation                       0x217d7229 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
22  CoreFoundation                       0x217d7015 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
23  GraphicsServices                     0x22dc7ac9 GSEventRunModal + 158
24  UIKit                                0x25eab189 UIApplicationMain + 142
25  My App.                              0x0005376b main (main.m:14)
26  ???                                  0x2147f873 0x0 + 0
```

Comment: Same problem here, I can't find how to fix it. :(